# sharing & storing IV for AES Encryption/decryption

Tags: php, android, encryption, aes

I am currently using AES-ECB encryption for user passwords on an android app, but I have to connect this app's database to a website where users can register and log in the same way as the mobile app.

I have read that ECB mode is not secured, so I wanted to use CBC by generating an IV.

Is it secure to store an IV as a constant in the code (I store the secret key this way too), both in php on the server side, and in the app ?

If not, is there a way for the website and the mobile app to share it's IV to encrypt /decrypt user password ?

Alternatively, I may have chosen the wrong encryption algorithm, there might be one that better suit my needs

Answer (score 6):

Best practice would be to create a new random IV for each encryption. The IV is basically a seed for that encryption call used in the first block.

Each IV can be safely stored in clear text along with the cypher text so it is available when decrypting the cypher text (the IV used to encrypt must be the same IV used to decrypt).

Comment: but in this way for the login, the user password has to be stored clear on the server, so that the server can decrypt the hash using the secret key and the iv and then compare it to the clear password in the db. It wouldn't be possible to only compare hashes, because of the changing IV

Comment: So if I have understood you have a mobile application I can logon to with some credentials and also a website I should be able to log into with the same credentials? Do I need to be able to login in offline mode to the mobile app?

Comment: exactly, but as I don't want to store clear passwords on the server's db, I might have used the wrong algorithm, I should maybe encrypt the password with a salted MD5, then encrypt it with RSA using a hardcoded public key in the app

Comment: The recommended method of deriving a hash from a password is to use a key derivation function such as PBKF2, bcrypt or scrypt.

Comment: For passwords absolutely use one of the KDF's @owlstead recommends. The scenario of encrypting an MD5 hash offers your users far less than using a properly tuned strong hash function like PBKDF2. An attacker would just need to recover the key and crack open Hashcat to break your md5 hash. That's because MD5 was designed to be fast and KDF's are designed to be slow. If you need transport security use SSL.

Answer (score 1):

If you are fixed with this algorithm, I may suggest - ***not to share IV*** from encrypting end to decrypting end.

**Dummy Blocks**
    Add an initial dummy block of 16 bytes before your actual message block of 16 bytes. So that, even if you are not sharing IV to the Decrypting End, as AES-CBC is a chaining mode, the first block (dummy block) at Decrypting end will be corrupted and rest of the blocks are not affected.

**Encrypting End**
As per CBC mode in AES, In CBC mode, each block of plaintext is XORed with the previous ciphertext block before being encrypted. 
To make each message unique, an initialization vector must be used in the first block.
Refer: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_Block_Chaining_.28CBC.29

**Decrypting End**
Decrypting with the incorrect IV causes the first block of plaintext to be corrupt but subsequent plaintext blocks will be correct. 
This is because a plaintext block can be recovered from two adjacent blocks of ciphertext.