# AES Encryption without using IV

Tags: c#, encryption, encryption-symmetric, initialization-vector

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aes(v=vs.110).aspx

I am planning to use the AES to encrypt/decrypt my messages.
I do not want to use the IV while encrypting/decrypting because I am already securing my Key in KeyVault and I just want to share only one Key to the other parties who can decrypt my messages.

Any suggestions? How can I make IV as optional/removed.

Comment: Do you even understand the purpose of the IV here in the first place?

Comment: possible duplicate of [sharing & storing IV for AES Encryption/decryption](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13819231/sharing-storing-iv-for-aes-encryption-decryption)

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But I do not want to use..

Comment: Your question is somewhat analogous to saying "I want to encrypt with AES, but I don't want it to be secure", is that really your intention?

Comment: My Key is secure. If I do not use the IV, I think that should be fine. As per the documentation "For a given secret key k, a simple block cipher that does not use an initialization vector will encrypt the same input block of plain text into the same output block of cipher text.". So IV is that much important when my ecryption key is secure?

Comment: Yes, the IV is important.  Without the IV, your encrypted message, "open the safe" as an example will be the same, every time, as long as it falls entirely within a single block.  Someone who knows this can know when you instructed the safe be opened even if they cannot decrypt anything else.  With the IV, nothing looks the same from one encrypt to the next even with identical plaintexts.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I agree now that we should use the IV. Can I keep the IV constant for all the messages?

Comment: No, the IV needs to change or it does no good.  Typically they use the IV then put the IV at the beginning of the crypto text.  It's only 16 bytes (for 128 bit blocksize) so it is small.  And the IV value does not have to be secret, so you concatenate the IV and crypto text and send, and then the recipient takes that IV to decrypt.  Next message is a new random IV.

Comment: Most crypto packages provide CBC as well as other modes.  CBC is very common though.  So CBC will want the IV.  You just give it those 16 bytes in an array and it will do the rest.